# How to avoid wrapper functions for classes within classes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, wrapper

*FYI - I am working on an introductory OOP project.  This seems like a basic issue but I can't find a clear explanation anywhere.

I am trying to avoid wrapper functions when calling member functions of objects that are private data members of other objects.  Below I have created a simple illustration of what I mean.  There is a top-level Game_Manager object that contains 2 Player objects that each contain a Weapon object.

Game_Manager knows when a player's weapon should attack.  Is there any way to avoid the wrapper function in Player?  Is this just bad design?

```
class Weapon
{
    public:
        void attack();
};

class Player
{
    public:
        void attack()
        {
            weapon.attack();
        }

    private:
        Weapon weapon;
};

class Game_Manager 
{
    public:
        time_for_first_player_to_attack()
        {
            player_1.attack();
        }

    private:
        Player player_1;
        Player player_2;
};
```

Comment: Another way to think about it is to just have the manager tell each object it manages that some period of time has elapsed and then have each object responsible for its own inner workings.

Comment: Curious -- What is wrong here? Why do you think it is bad design?

Comment: @Arun Well, I'm foreseeing a proliferation of wrappers simply to propagate instructions from the Game_Manager. The objects inside Player are really data structures representing groups of cards, and the progression of game play affects them directly. It may be that Player is more suited to be a struct, which we're not allowed to use...I'm still early in the design process.

Comment: @Retired Ninja: That's ideally what I want. It just seems that the "brain" of the Player is somewhat transparent and often just a function of what phase the game is in. Also, I want Player to query the user to make decisions.

Comment: @jibarish: Hmm... What if, in future, a player is allowed to acquire/carry/apply more than one weapon? What if an weapons is to be activated with a key possessed only by the respective player?

Comment: Struct and Class are exactly the same in every way except that Struct defaults to public access and Class defaults to private, so in essence if you're using a Class you're using a Struct.  You should probably think in terms of event driven interfaces rather than querying anything. Something happens, like a click or keypress and the entities interested in those events recieve and possibly consume them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Weapon getWeapon() { return weapon; } const;

    private:
        Weapon weapon;
};


class Game_Manager 
{
    public:
        time_for_first_player_to_attack()
        {
            player_1.getWeapon().attack();
        }

    private:
        Player player_1;
        Player player_2;
};
```

Comment: Sweet! One wrapper to wrap them all.

Comment: It may be practical sometimes, but it violates the Law of Demeter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: @JurajBlaho True, but in this design a 'Game_Manager' should supposedly have knowledge of all the public functions of all the important Game Element Classes.

Comment: I don't see any problem with OP's code. However, this solution, IMHO, breaks encapsulation (for the `Player` class).